# Question about folders/workspaces inside depot

Tags: perforce, unreal-engine4

I’d like to have one perforce depot and use multiple folders within that for different projects. My depot is setup with the custom local path Y:\depot, and I have a client with the workspace path E:\PerforceWorkspaces.

My client workspace path for project #1 is E:\PerforceWorkspaces\UEPerforceTest and inside here I have multiple files and folders.

My depot path for this project is Y:\depot, and all the files from the workspace are inside here, no UEPerforceTest folder.

This works fine, but if I add a new project folder eg TEST2, so the workspace path is E:\PerforceWorkspaces\TEST2 and then Get Latest on my other UEPerforceTest workspace, the TEST2 folder is downloaded. The depot path for this new project is the same the previous one (Y:\depot), so all the files are in there along with the other project.

So my question is this: how do keep different projects in separate folders in the depot, to allow workspaces to remain separate?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the actual client spec (`p4 client -o` output) as part of this question?  If the root for your workspace is ` E:\PerforceWorkspaces\UEPerforceTest` then the path `E:\PerforceWorkspaces\TEST2` would not be part of the workspace, and you would not be able to add it to the depot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the answer - use p4 client *clientname* to open the client settings then change the View line to whichever folder you need.

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier answer than changing the client every time you want to Get Latest. You can always choose to update only a portion of your workspace by either:

1. Right-clicking on the project you want to update and choosing Get Latest, or
2. From the command line: `p4 sync //depot/UEPerforceTest/...`

Another solution would be to use separate workspaces (one for each project). This will allow you to easily work on both at the same time.